# How to type into a iframe in selenium RC?

Tags: java, iframe, selenium, types, selenium-rc

The structure of html page is as below:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <iframe id="iframe-id">
    #document
      <html>
        <body contenteditable="true">
        </body>
      </html>
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to type some text in the contenteditable body.

I try it with code below, but it failed to fill the editable area.

```
selenium.selectFrame("//*[@id='iframe-id']");
selenium.type("//[@contenteditable='true']", "some text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium RC has been deprecated several years ago. It is advised that you switch to using Selenium WebDriver. Please note that Selenium 2 has both APIs available, and so, for downwards compatibility considerations, you are able to mix and match if you need to.

Here is how you would do this using WebDriver API:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-id");
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body"));
body.click();
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = 'Hello World!'", body);
```